# laravel tablename found issue after create baseModel

Tags: php, model, eloquent, laravel-5.4, extends

i have a problem about table name in model. Normally i use Model class for extends but i changed it and write a BaseModel class and i extend this but i got

> "table not found error"

i write this code in anyModel:

> protected $table = 'user';

but not working.

baseModel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;

class BaseModel extends Model {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

any model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\BaseModel;

class User extends BaseModel {

   protected $table = 'users';

   .
   .
   .

}
```

where is the problem ?

where am i doing wrong ?

help ...

Comment: do you have namespace ?

Comment: yes i have a namespace

Comment: hey . help me please .

Comment: If you `User` model and your `BaseModel` are in the same namespace then you don't need to add `use App\Models\BaseModel`. Can you show the stack trace for the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution which is issued by cache. i cleared it and gone . thanks everybody ...